# append multiple child blocks from controller

Tags: magento-1.8, layout, controllers

I'm trying to append more than one block from controller.

The code I've written is

```
            $this->loadLayout();
            $layout = $this->getLayout();
            $layout->getBlock('root')->setTemplate('page/1column.phtml');
            $noResult = $layout->getBlock('search.result')->setTemplate('excatsearch/noresult.phtml');
            $newArrival = $layout->createBlock('Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New', 'new_arrivals', array(
                'template' => 'excatsearch/newarrival.phtml'
            ));
            $bestSellers = $layout->createBlock('Mage_Page_Block_Html', 'best_sellers', array(
                'template' => 'excatsearch/best_seller.phtml'
            ));
            $noResult->append($newArrival)
            ->append($bestSellers);
            $this->renderLayout();
```

and code in `noresult.phtml` is

```
$this->getChildHtml();
```

But I'm only able to see the `new_arrival` block not `best_sellers`. So, How can I add the other block?

Comment: Did you try clearing the cache?

Comment: my cache are already disabled and yes, I'd cleared them again. but no changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo $this->getChildHtml();
```

Should work.
Do tell me if it worked.
Also, use `setTemplate` instead of passing as an attribute:

```
$this->loadLayout();
$layout = $this->getLayout();
$layout->getBlock('root')->setTemplate('page/1column.phtml');
$noResult = $layout->getBlock('search.result')->setTemplate('excatsearch/noresult.phtml');
$newArrival = $layout->createBlock('Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New', 'new_arrivals')
              ->setTemplate('excatsearch/newarrival.phtml');
$bestSellers = $layout->createBlock('Mage_Page_Block_Html', 'best_sellers')
               ->setTemplate('excatsearch/best_seller.phtml');
$noResult->append($newArrival)
         ->append($bestSellers);
$this->renderLayout();
```

Comment: yes. `echo $this->getChildHtml();` is working fine. but the problem seems to be in appending a block from controller

Comment: @MohammadFaisal are you using [Magento Debug](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magneto-debug.html)? Try using it, and see if the blocks are there, even though not rendered

Comment: I'd used `template path hint` but my block/phtml file is not there

Comment: @MohammadFaisal I updated my answer

Comment: thanks! it works fine. But what was the problem with passing template as **`attribute`**?

Comment: @MohammadFaisal by looking at the code, I didn't see any immediate indication that It'll actually set the template file if you pass it as a `template` attribute.

Comment: but that code works fine for the first block? the rest of the block were not added after

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12885/discussion-between-dror-and-mohammad-faisal)